# send argument in gitlab-ci to a python project

Tags: parameter-passing, gitlab-ci, git-stage

Recently I created a project and dockerize it.
in order to write a **.gitlab-ci.yml**, I want to prepare a test stage to test my program.

in the middle of my python code, I ask from the user a username and password,
but because in the gitlab-ci, everything should be executed automatically, I want to send username and password inside my gitlab-ci instead of reading from the input.
how can I send a username and password which is a static phrase to my python code inside of my gitlab-ci?

**Please pay attention that I don't want to use sys.args in my python code, because in real execution I want to read it from user really, but just in gitlab-ci, I want to send a specific username and password to that program so it can execute automatically.**

Comment: Actually I used pass phrase to read username and password. Now after running my script, I want to send username and password automatically from gilab-ci.

Answer (score 2):

You can use environment variables in GitLab to send username and password to your script:

https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/variables/#custom-environment-variables

These variables will then be available to your program in your gitlab-ci.yml file. How you access the variables depend on which shell you are using (cmd, powershell, sh, bash):

https://docs.gitlab.com/runner/shells/#overview

You can use it in some way like this:

```
myjob:
  stage: test
  script:
    - python myscript.py --username $username --password $password
```

Exactly how you get the username and password into your program is up to you. If you don't want to use command line arguments, you might be able to create a little helper script that sends in the username and password through stdin. Another alternative is to add command line arguments to make it easy to test your program.